# How can I construct an if statement for numpy arrays' elements comparison, to produce a new array with same dimension?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[3.5,6,8,2]])
b = np.array([[6,2,8,2]])
c = np.array([[2,3,7,5]])
d = np.array([[3,2,5,1]])
if a > b:
    e = 2*a+6*c
else:
    e = 3*c + 4*d

print(e)
```

then I got

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and if I type in print(e), I got

```
[2, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1]
```

The e I want to construct is an array that has the same dimension with a,b,c,d , and the if statement that decides what equation will be used to make each element.

In other words, for the elements in of the first place of a and b: 3.5<6, so e = 3*c + 4*d = 3*2 + 4*3 = 18
For the second elements: 6>2, e = 2*a+6*c = 2*6 + 6*3 = 30

Third: 8=8, e = 3*c + 4*d = 3*7 + 4*5 = 41

Fourth: 2 = 2, e = 3*c + 4*d = 3*5 + 4*1 = 19

e = [18,30,41,19]

I tried to find someone who asked about constructing a script doing such things, but I could find none, and all numpy questions about if statement(or equivalent) did not help. Thanks.(It seems that a.all or a.any from the python recommendation did not help as well.)

Comment: Seems like a use case for [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: `if` is a one time action, not a 'for each element' iterator.

Comment: @hpaulj many people who are new to Numpy get confused because Numpy data types cause a lot of operations to "broadcast", but there is nothing Numpy can do to make the *language syntax* also broadcast - so it creates awkward seams. `a * b` multiplies elementwise; `a == b` compares elementwise; but the result of that elementwise comparison can't be used to do conditional work elementwise.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, this is a clear cases where they want an element-wise application.  In other cases it isn't so clear, even to the poster.  The `all/any` suggestion isn't always helpful, but suggesting a concise element-wise fix is harder.  I think the error is actually produced by `(x>0).__bool__()`, which is called (by the interpreter?) any time the code expects a boolean value - such as `if`, `or`.  `pandas` and `sympy` have there own versions of the `ambiguity` error.

Comment: Yes, the error is produced by boolean conversion. There are various fixes depending on what the user is trying to do, and understanding the problem is a general topic that is well covered at the now-linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`:

> Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.

```
e = np.where(a > b, 2*a+6*c, 3*c + 4*d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [370]: a = np.array([[3.5,6,8,2]])
     ...: b = np.array([[6,2,8,2]])
     ...: c = np.array([[2,3,7,5]])
     ...: d = np.array([[3,2,5,1]])
     ...: 
In [371]: a.shape
Out[371]: (1, 4)
In [372]: a[0].shape
Out[372]: (4,)
```

The problem with the `if` is that `a>b` is an array. There's no one True/False value to "switch" on:

```
In [373]: a>b
Out[373]: array([[False,  True, False, False]])
```

`where` does the array "switch"; an equivalent way is:

```
In [376]: mask = a>b
In [377]: e = 3*c + 4*d
In [378]: e
Out[378]: array([[18, 17, 41, 19]])
In [379]: e[mask] = 2*a[mask] + 6*c[mask]
In [380]: e
Out[380]: array([[18, 30, 41, 19]])
```

`np.where` itself does not iterate (many `pandas` users seem assume it does).  It works with the whole arrays, the condition array (my `mask`) and the whole array values.

To use the `if`, we have to work with scalar values, not arrays.  Wrap the `if/else` in a loop.   For example:

```
In [381]: alist = []
In [382]: for i,j,k,l in zip(a[0],b[0],c[0],d[0]):
     ...:     if i>j:
     ...:         f = 2*i+6*k
     ...:     else:
     ...:         f = 3*k+4*l
     ...:     alist.append(f)
     ...: 
In [383]: alist
Out[383]: [18, 30.0, 41, 19]
```

This works because `i` and `j` are single numbers, not arrays.